# Label in Datepicker in Material UI not centered

Tags: material-ui

I have followed the simple example on [Matererial-UI](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/date-picker)

```js
import React from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'material-ui/lib/date-picker/date-picker';

const DatePickerExampleSimple = () => (
  <div>
    <DatePicker hintText="Portrait Dialog" />
    <DatePicker hintText="Landscape Dialog" mode="landscape" />
    <DatePicker hintText="Dialog Disabled" disabled={true} />
  </div>
);
```

But the output (image below) is not right, the blue label is not centered.

I am using: Material UI version 0.15.0-alpha.2, React 0.14.7, chrome 49

Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: This is a new regression with 0.15.0-alpha.2. On the demo site, if you can change it back to 0.15.0-alpha.1 or 14.4, and probably every one before that, it behaves as expected. I suggest that you submit a bug report on the GitHub site.

Answer (score 0):

The DatePicker is being redesigned at the moment and this issue should be fixed among others soon. 
Watch this Pull-Request for updates:
https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/pull/3739

If you need the layout fixed immediatly, use 0.15.0-alpha.1 or older